# Express mongoose populate array of subdocuments from POST

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my Mongoose Schema:

```
const InvoiceSchema = new Schema({
name: { type: String, required: true },
description: { type: String },

items: [{
    product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
    amount: { type: Number },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    quantity: { type: Number },
    rate: { type: Number, required: true }
}],
createdBy: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
}
```

Now I want to populate my Schema from POST Datas, My problem is I don't Know how to post my items (How do I name my fields)??

I use PostMan to post Datas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get post data

**To add a new record in mongoose**

```
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema.Types;
const newInvoice = new InvoiceSchema({
  name: "John Smith",
  description: "This is a description",
  items: [{
    product: 'THIS_IS_AN_OBJECT_ID_STRINGIFIED',
    amount: 2,
    quantity: 5,
    //name - comes from the product model
    //rate - comes from the product model
  }]
});

newInvoice.save();
```

**To POST and save it**

```
//Response format
{
  name: 'John Smith',
  description: 'This is a description',
  items: [
    {
      product: 'THIS_IS_AN_OBJECT_ID',
      amount: 2,
      quantity: 5
    }
  ]
}

app.post('/yourRoute', (req, res) => {
  const {name, description, items} = req.body;
  const newInvoice = new InvoiceSchema({name, description, items});
  newInvoice.save().then(()=>res.send('success'))
});
```

Comment: But how should I name my Items Fields in FrontEnd??

Comment: If you are using Postman, you can send the JSON in the format I have given you.  You should be able to literally put that into Postman and have it handle the request.  If you have having troubles `console.log(req.body)` and that should output your POST data to your log.

Comment: As far as naming them goes, they should have the same names on the front end as the back.

Comment: @medKHELIFI   If my answer helped you, could you upvote it?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**To bulk add items**

```js
const invoice = new Invoice();
invoice.items = req.body.items;
```

**To add single item**

```js
invoice.items.push(item);
```

**To update single item**

```
const item = invoice.items.id(req.params._id);
item.attribute = ...
// Do update
```